# How long until a new cat gets settled?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, fear

So I've recently rescued a 10 month old cat. Nobody really knew her background and I only got told that she's aggressive. The foster home I got her from said she's not aggressive at all. Then in the next breath said to ignore her if she hisses at me.

She's been with us for nearly a week now. I see progress in her, she will explore at night. She goes and sits on our chair in the living room and I have found her on our bed sleeping when I come in from work. However, most of the time when I talk or go near her she will start making a strange sniffing noise followed by hissing and growling. It's very strange to me too because she has came over before and sat on my lap. I stroked her then and for some reason she lashed out hissing and growling at my face. But she wouldn't get off my lap. I don't know if it's the case of her needing time to settle more, or if it's the case of her actually being an aggressive cat?

I don't want an aggressive cat so if she doesn't change her ways after so long then I will have to take her back. I feel terrible about it but I know I am not the person to help her with this behavioural problem (if this is the case).

Comment: She's not aggressive, just scared. Give her time.

Comment: Try not to take it personally. She doesn't "hate" you and likely is just not settled in to her new home. Just take it slow with giving her affection. It is a good sign that she sits in your lap, but her reaction to stroking is just her way of saying "not yet." Your patience with her will be rewarded in time.

Comment: Any update on how this turned out for you?

Answer (score 4):

Give her time. She's in new place that's unfamiliar for her. However, the fact she is hissing suggests she had been hurt by people in the past. Over time she will understand that she can trust you, however that might take some time.