# New Cat! How can I help her become my friend?

Tags: cats, adoption

I recently adopted a 2.5 year old cat from a rescue.

What we did in preparation:

Got her a litter box
Arranged a bed for her to sleep on
A separate space where she could be comfortable

The rescue guy came and thought the place we had prepped up wasn’t the best because there was no natural light there. So quickly changes strategy, opened up the bathroom downstairs and left the litter box and food in there.

How it’s been going:

Day 1: bunted against us, then went and hid behind the toilet. Sat there the whole day, ate a little but remained there. Gave us slow blinks from a distance and sometimes bunted.

By evening, the toilet seemed too cold so I got her to the space that we had prepped for her. Stayed there, purred and kneaded as we groomed her. Ate all of her wet food , but did not see her drink water. But, at night started exhibiting fear and ran back to the toilet and hid under the sink cabinet.

Day 2: Morning - again bunted all of us,  increased her radius of the areas she explored but kept her tail between her feet and looked around for a hiding spot. Went upstairs and hid under the bed. Did not eat. I went and napped in the same room and then lay down and gave her slow blinks. She stared back (no slow blinks) and then when I moved away from her, she went and hid somewhere else (changed hiding place).

What am I doing wrong, how can I help her become one of us soon?

Comment: You might also find some good information in this question (but the answer to the first one appears to be a better fit to your situation): https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16701/how-long-until-a-new-cat-gets-settled

Comment: For day one and two it seems to be a good start, if you can groom her and carry her to another place. Seems to be a calm cat in my opinion